# How should I send emails with From: address of my B2B SaaS customers?

Tags: sendgrid, email, saas

I am building a B2B SaaS platform which sends emails on behalf of it's business clients.  Currently, using Sendgrid.

Assuming that Client's domain name is blabla.com
How can I send emails with  field "from": noreply@blabla.com ?

According to Sendgrid's documentation, the "From" field should be either from verified domain or verified single address.

1. **Verified domain** doesn't seem like a feasible option, as it requires every customer to change their DNS records. Some of the customers just don't have easy access to their domain names.
2. **Verified single address** seems to be a better option, but according to Sendgrid the upper limit is 100 of such addresses
   Additionally, they don't allow to brand a verification email being sent on adding new verified single address.

What is the best practice to send emails on behalf of your business clients?

Are there better approaches to solve this problem?

Comment: I am currently searching for a solution to this exact issue. Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: @Brett we ended up building the first option, where the customer needs to connect a domain using DNS. Also, we are not using subaccounts for that.

Comment: Stuck with the same problem. The first option is not user-friendly and can hinder us to acquire new customers easily. Please help.